# parseInt is returning NaN for CSS property

Tags: javascript, css

The code below is returning `NaN` in the prompt.

```
var left = parseInt(document.getElementById('box').style.left, 10);

if (key.keyCode == 37) {
    var new_left = (left - 50) + 'px';
    document.getElementById('box').style.left = new_left;
    left = new_left;
}

alert(new_left);
```

Even if I use `left` instead of `new_left` it returns `NaN`

I'm sure it's to do with how I'm getting the value, but how else can I get it?

No jQuery please. Thanks

Comment: What does alert(document.getElementById('box').style.left); return?

Comment: It's because the value includes `px` - try stripping that out first.

Comment: naddiseo it returns nothing (blank). mark, I thought parseInt would remove the px. jonathan, it's a string. thanks

Comment: @MarkParnell - no it's not: _parseInt()_ ignores trailing non-digit characters (though of course it returns NaN if there aren't digit characters at the beginning). Cantsay - you need to allow for when _style.left_ is blank.

Comment: @cantsay, if it's returning blank, then that's your problem. parseInt('') is NaN.

Comment: I think you are setting left from a stylesheet, so you need getComputedStyle (+ alternatives for cross-browser compatibility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the element has a style.left to begin with?
parseInt("", 10) results in NaN

Try this:

```
var left = parseInt(document.getElementById('box').style.left || 0, 10);
```

Comment: I've set left using CSS (`left: 100px;`) - the CSS is in the head of the document, the JS is between the closing body and html tags. thanks

Comment: I think that the style.left property is specifically for inline CSS. For example:
<div style='left:100px'></div>

Comment: thanks! this worked. any idea how I can do it with CSS in a stylesheet though, to keep the HTML/CSS seperate?

Comment: Well it depends on what you are trying to do. You may want to use something like element.offsetLeft.